# echo json_encode($data) funciona en mi servidor de producción pero en localhost no

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xampp

Tengo un código que consiste en `html5`, `jquery`,`ajax` y `php`, la aplicación funciona correctamente en mi servidor de producción, sin embargo, cuando la llevo a desarrollo *(localhost)* no funciona, las librerías apuntan correctamente.

Si en lugar de poner `echo` pongo `print_r()` si funciona y el error que manda después de dos veces dar enter es el siguiente:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/json

¿Me podrían apoyar?

Este es mi código:

```
 <?php
$data = array();
include('opendb.php');

$noHDs = '2';
$noHDMASs = '1';
$noSDs ='0';
$eqhd = '0';
$eqplus = '3';
$paq = utf8_decode('paquete');
$idMaster = '010B4A';
$idSlv1 = '010B25';
$idSlv2 = '';
$idSlv3 = '';
$equiposAct = '2';
$noEmp = '34586';


if($equiposAct==1){
    $txt = " AND irds LIKE '%$idMaster%'";
}
if($equiposAct==2){
    $txt = " AND (irds LIKE '%$idMaster%' OR irds LIKE '%$idSlv1%')";
}
if($equiposAct==3){
    $txt = " AND (irds LIKE '%$idMaster%' OR irds LIKE '%$idSlv1%' OR irds LIKE '%$idSlv2%')";
}
if($equiposAct==4){
    $txt = " AND (irds LIKE '%$idMaster%' OR irds LIKE '%$idSlv1%' OR irds LIKE '%$idSlv2%' OR irds LIKE '%$idSlv3%')";
}



$data['noHDs'] =  $noHDs;
$data['noHDMASs'] = $noHDMASs;
$data['noSDs'] = $noSDs;
$data['eqhd'] = $eqhd;
$data['eqplus'] = $eqplus;
$data['paq'] = $paq;
$data['idMaster'] = $idMaster;
$data['idSlv1'] = $idSlv1;
$data['idSlv2'] = $idSlv2;
$data['idSlv3'] = $idSlv3;

$data['master'] = '';
$data['sl1']='';
$data['sl2']='';
$data['sl3']='';


$data['var'] = '';


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `nomenclatura` WHERE tieneHD='$noHDs' AND tieneHDplus='$noHDMASs' AND tieneSD='$noSDs' AND quiereHD='$eqhd' AND quiereHDplus='$eqplus'".$txt;

$rs = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($rs);
if($num > 0)
{

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
    $sqlCons = "SELECT * from consultas WHERE noEmp = '$noEmp' AND fecha ='$fecha'";

    $rsCons = mysql_query($sqlCons)or die(mysql_error());
    $numCons = mysql_num_rows($rsCons);
    $j = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $idConsulta = "CONS-".date('ymdHisu');
    $insCons = "INSERT INTO consultas VALUES('$idConsulta','$noEmp','$fecha','$j')";
    $insRs = mysql_query($insCons) or die(mysql_error());

    $dtdb = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Consulta realizada ';
    $idRel = $dtdb['idRel'];

    $data['nomemcla'] = $dtdb['nomenclatura'].'**'.$dtdb['caso'];
    $data['tipoEquipo'] = $dtdb['tipoEquipo'];
    $pos = strpos($dtdb['nomenclatura'].'**'.$dtdb['caso'], "]");
    if ($pos === false) {
        $data['cnomenclat'] = $dtdb['nomenclatura'].'**'.$dtdb['caso'];
    } else {
        $data['cnomenclat'] = substr($dtdb['nomenclatura'].'**'.$dtdb['caso'],$pos+1);
    }

    $sqlComps = "SELECT * from componentes WHERE idRel='$idRel'";

    $rsComps = mysql_query($sqlComps)or die(mysql_error());
    $dtComps = mysql_fetch_array($rsComps);
    $data['compAdd'] = utf8_encode($dtComps['compAdd']);
    $data['costoAdd'] = $dtComps['costoAdd'];
    $data['compMig'] = utf8_encode($dtComps['compMig']);
    $data['costoMig'] = $dtComps['costoMig'];
    $data['costoTot'] = "$ ".$dtComps['costoTot'];
    if($data['costoAdd']!=NULL) $data['costoAdd']="$ ".$data['costoAdd'];
    if($data['costoMig']!=NULL) $data['costoMig']="$ ".$data['costoMig'];

    $sqlPaq = "SELECT * from paquetes WHERE idRel='$idRel' AND master = '$paq' ";

    $rsPaq = mysql_query($sqlPaq)or die(mysql_error());
    $dtPaq = mysql_fetch_array($rsPaq);

    $data['var']="100";

    $data['preciolista'] = str_replace(',', "",$dtPaq['preciolista']); 
    $data['pagoOportuno'] = str_replace(',', "",$dtPaq['pagoOportuno']);
    $data['pagoOportuno'] = "$ ".$data['pagoOportuno'];
    $data['preciolista'] = "$ ".$data['preciolista'];


    $sqlMaster = "SELECT master from paquetes WHERE idRel='$idRel' AND paquete = '$paq' GROUP BY master ";

    $rsMaster = mysql_query($sqlMaster)or die(mysql_error());
    while($dtMaster = mysql_fetch_array($rsMaster)){
        $data['master'] .= '</br>'.$dtMaster['master'];
    }
    $data['master'] .= '</br>';

    $sqlSL1 = "SELECT slave1 from paquetes WHERE idRel='$idRel' AND paquete = '$paq' GROUP BY slave1 ";

    $rsSL1 = mysql_query($sqlSL1)or die(mysql_error());
    while($dtSL1 = mysql_fetch_array($rsSL1)){
        $data['sl1'] .= '</br>'.$dtSL1['slave1'];
    }
    $data['sl1'] .= '</br>';

    $sqlSL2 = "SELECT slave2 from paquetes WHERE idRel='$idRel' AND paquete = '$paq' GROUP BY slave2 ";

    $rsSL2 = mysql_query($sqlSL2)or die(mysql_error());
    while($dtSL2 = mysql_fetch_array($rsSL2)){
        $data['sl2'] .= '</br>'.$dtSL2['slave2'];
    }
    $data['sl2'] .= '</br>';

    $sqlSL3 = "SELECT slave3 from paquetes WHERE idRel='$idRel' AND paquete = '$paq' GROUP BY slave3 ";

    $rsSL3 = mysql_query($sqlSL3)or die(mysql_error());
    while($dtSL3 = mysql_fetch_array($rsSL3)){
        $data['sl3'] .= '</br>'.$dtSL3['slave3'];
    }
    $data['sl3'] .= '</br>';    
}
else{
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['message'] = 'La combinación no existe en migración ';

}
mysql_close($conn);
$data['hr']=date('H:i:s');
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Edita tu pregunta agregando la descripción de los errores que tengas. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Elizabeth , Seria bueno que organices el codigo para que se vea mejor ordenado, encuanto al echo y el print_r resulta, que cuando das print_r te funciona ya que lo que estas imprimiendo es un arreglo y el echo jamas imprimira un arreglo.

Comment: Trata de organizar tu código, ya que algunos host no permiten que el PHP este tan junto, osea separa las variables de los "=" y también el valor de la variable, por ejemplo: así esta tu código $data='valor'; y debería estar así $data = 'valor';

Answer (score 1):

pueden ser un par de problemas:

- Tu llamada AJAX no está esperando explícitamente JSON; en el llamado AJAX en JQuery puedes definir que esperas como respuesta:

  `var request = $.ajax({ url:"script.php", method:"POST", data:{id :98}, dataType:"json" });`
- Tu script PHP está generando output antes de enviar el header `header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8')`; usa las herramientas de desarrollo de tu browser para revisar la respuesta que genera tu script, revisa los headers de respuesta para ver si coinciden. Si tu respuesta tiene algun error o caracter que no coincida con el formato json entonces esa puede ser la causa.

Básicamente necesitas revisar el output del script para determinar el error... si no puedes ver los errores en el archivo porque la respuesta está en blanco necesitarás activar los errores de PHP, usa las siguientes líneas al inicio de tu script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```